# rails 3 - escaping partial's generated html in javascript response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view

I am trying to do a simple thing where:

**_flash.js.erb:**

```
$("#alerts").append("<%=j render :template => "shared/_flash.html.erb" %>");
```

Note the <%=j... which escapes the javascript.

**_flash.html.erb:**

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert-message top <%= "#{key}" %> fade in" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
    <p><%=j value %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When _flash.js.erb is called, however, something like the following is appended:

```
$("#alerts").append("  \u003Cdiv class=alert-message top warning fade in data-alert=alert\u003E
    \u003Ca class=close href=#\u003Ex\u003C/a\u003E
    \u003Cp\u003ELooks like you have already linked with Facebook.\u003C/p\u003E
  \u003C/div\u003E
");
```

Without the javascript escaping, the response is like this:

```
$("#alerts").append("  <div class="alert-message top warning fade in" data-alert="alert">
    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
    <p>Looks like you have already linked with Facebook.</p>
  </div>
");
```

In the first response, TOO much stuff is escaped. In the second response, nothing is escaped  and the double quotes mess things up.

What is the recommended way in rails 3 to achieve the above in a robust fashion?

Comment: So turns out that using escape_javascript(...) instead of <%=j .. %> yields the desired results. Weird - thought they were the same thing. I guess I will have to settle with more verbosity. Any less verbose alternatives or a way to make <%=j ... %> work?

Answer (score 3):

Use `escape_javascript` instead; you're [JSON-escaping](http://apidock.com/rails/ERB/Util/json_escape/class) it.

You could alias something the same way `j` is an alias to `json_escape`; it's just a helper.

Comment: Someone needs to fix these docs then --http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript